# How to determine the number of negation words per sentence

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know how to count how many negative words (`no, not`) and abbreviation (`n't`) there are in a sentence and in the whole text.
For number of sentences I am applying the following one:

```
df["sent"]=df['text'].str.count('[\w][\.!\?]')
```

However this gives me the count of sentences in a text. I would need to look per each sentence at the number of negation words and within the whole text.
Can you please give me some tips?

The expected output for `text` column is shown below

```
text                                   sent     count_n_s     count_tot
I haven't tried it yet                  1          1              1
I do not like it. What do you think?    2         0.5             1
It's marvellous!!!                      1          0              0
No, I prefer the other one.             2          1              1
```

count_n_s is given by counting the total number of negotiation words per sentence, then dividing by the number of sentences.

I tried

```
split_w = re.split("\w+",df['text'])

neg_words=['no','not','n\'t']
words = [w for i,w in enumerate(split_w) if i and (split_w[i-1] in neg_words)]
```

Comment: As you've already mentioned, you need to separate the sentences, and count negations in each.  What part of this has you stuck?  Please post the problem code, the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Since the individual techniques are available from any tutorial on strings, I'm not clear where you have trouble.

Comment: I provided an example with also expected output. I just updated question with what I have tried

Comment: Your example does not run; the data frame isn't defined.  What output do you actually get from the code?  Again, please refer to the MRE description.  We should be able to cut-paste a contiguous block of your posting, run it, and reproduce your given output.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would get a count of total negations in the text (not for individual sentences):

```
import re

NEG = r"""(?:^(?:no|not)$)|n't"""

NEG_RE = re.compile(NEG, re.VERBOSE)

def get_count(text):
    count = 0
    for word in text:
        if NEG_RE .search(word):
            count+=1
            continue
        else:
            pass
    return count
df['text_list'] =  df['text'].apply(lambda x: x.split())
df['count'] = df['text_list'].apply(lambda x: get_count(x))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Darcey. I have appreciated your help and mark this question as it has been absolutely useful to me :)

Answer (score 0):

To get count of negations for individual lines use the code below. For words like haven't you can add it to neg_words since it is not a negation if you strip the word of everything else if it has n't

```
import re

str1 = '''I haven't tried it yet
I do not like it. What do you think?
It's marvellous!!!
No, I prefer the other one.'''

neg_words=['no','not','n\'t']
for text in str1.split('\n'):
    split_w = re.split("\s", text.lower())
    # to get rid of special characters such as comma in 'No,' use the below search
    split_w = [re.search('^\w+', w).group(0) for w in split_w]
    words = [w for w in split_w if w in neg_words]
    print(len(words))
```